# Pivoting a table in SQL, where the new columns are based on every possible combination of values from two columns

Tags: oracle

To illustrate, the following table:

| ID | Model | Series | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | productX | SeriesZ | 1000 |
| 001 | productX | SeriesABC | 2000 |
| 001 | productX | SeriesABC | 8000 |
| 002 | productY | SeriesABC | 5000 |

should be transformed such that each record captures a unique id and the total amount it has contributed to each model-series possible combination.

| ID | productX_SeriesZ | productX_SeriesABC | productY_SeriesABC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1000 | 10000 | 0 |
| 002 | 0 | 0 | 5000 |

Can I use the pivot function to pivot on for each possible combination of values in two columns?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: thought that was irrelevant, I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
        SUM( CASE WHEN model = 'productX' and series = 'SeriesZ' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) productX_SeriesZ,
        SUM( CASE WHEN model = 'productX' and series = 'SeriesABC' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) productX_SeriesABC,
        SUM( CASE WHEN model = 'productY' and series = 'SeriesABC' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) productX_SeriesABC
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

EDIT:

"Works for this particular case, but what if we have hundreds of models and series?"

You can try this.

```
DECLARE
    
     TYPE model_rec IS RECORD ( mr mytable.model%type);
     TYPE series_rec IS RECORD ( sr mytable.series%type);

     TYPE model_tab IS TABLE OF model_rec;
     TYPE series_tab IS TABLE OF series_rec;

     mv model_tab;
     sv serie_tab;

     query varchar2(32767) := 'SELECT ID';

BEGIN 
    
     SELECT DISTINCT model, series INTO mv, sv FROM mytable WHERE model IS NOT NULL AND series IS NOT NULL;

     FOR i IN 1..mv.COUNT
     LOOP
     
     query := query||', SUM( CASE WHEN model = '|| DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE(mv(i).mr) 
                   || ' and  series = ' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE(sv(i).sr)||' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) ' ||  mv(i).mr||'_'||sv(i).sr||' '
      
     END LOOP;

     query := query || ' FROM mytable GROUP BY id;'
     
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;

END;
```

This may contain syntactic errors and can be optimized and refactored but this is the basic idea. I am in hurry so wrote it down without testing.

Comment: Works for this particular case, but what if we have hundreds of models and series?

Comment: Well, both answers need prior knowledge of model and series to work, if the number is large then use dynamic SQL in PLSQL block. fetch the model and series and prepare a query something like the given answer. you will need to take care of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query should work for you -

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID
              ,Model
              ,Series
          FROM YOUR_TABLE)
  PIVOT(SUM(AMOUNT) FOR Model IN ('productX' productx, 'productY' producty),
        SUM(AMOUNT) FOR Series IN ('SeriesABC' Seriesabc, 'SeriesZ' Seriesz))
```

Comment: What if don't have the luxury of stating all the available products and series values?